# How to prevent re-rendering of a children component which has no props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following parent component in React;

```
const Landing = () => {
    const { setHash, fetchError, fetchingMenu, fetchingConfig, fetchingCart, 
SelectedMenuSet, SelectedMerchant, Config } = useContext(DataContext);

    const hash = getHash();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (hash) setHash(hash);
    }, [hash, setHash])

    if (!hash) return <Error ReturnCode={600} Language={getBrowserLanguage()} />
    if (fetchingConfig || fetchingCart || fetchingMenu) return <Spinner />;
    if (fetchError) return <Error ReturnCode={fetchError} 
Language{getBrowserLanguage()}/>

    if (SelectedMenuSet.Layout === MenuLayout.Tile) return <Redirect to={'/tile'} />;
    else {
        if (Config.ShowMerchantList && !SelectedMerchant) return <Wellcome />

        return <Redirect to={`${hash}/carousel/0`} />;
    }}

export default Landing;
```

And i have a Loading page;

```
const Spinner = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    console.log("rerender")

    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <div className={classes.spinner}>
                <img className={classes.logo} alt="Logo" src={logo} />
                <br />
                <LinearProgress className={classes.progress} />
            </div>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}

export default memo(Spinner);
```

I have some states on my DataContext and depends to these states i render different pages in the Landing page. Loading page is dependent to these states. For example im fetching a menu and its config in the DataContext, and when i start fetching, i set fetchingMenu true. When these states change, my child component re-renders itself. I tried to solve this problem with React.memo but it did not work.

Is there any solution to solve this re-rendering except memo or useMemo? If there is not how can i solve this problem with memo?

Comment: What you're probably seeing is not rerendering but remounting because Spinner is rendered conditionally.

Comment: I tried to render Spinner unconditionally at the top of Landing page but it still re-rendering the Spinner page.

Comment: Did you try using `React.memo` when rendering Spinner unconditionally?

Comment: The component itself has already React.memo. Should i do that in the Landing page?

Comment: Is it possible for you to create codesandbox? How many times do you see `rerender` in the console?

Comment: In my project, i see it 8 times. I don't know how to create my project in codesandbox.